# timestamp sql query

Tags: java, sql

im try to execute sql query that will check if some time (like 10 sec) past from last timestamp update  in my table and chenge other table  if yes.

My question is if ther is any time-stamp conditional operator that can check this? For example
    < , > ,=?

(I know that I can do it in to different query, but I'm try do to it in 1 query)..

Something like this

```
             UPDATE Person SET isconnected=false 
            where person.email=(select from imalive where timestamp<10).
```

**person:**

email: dan@gmail.com

name: dan

age: 20

**isAlive:**

email: dan@gmail.com

lastseen: 2011-09-04 21:27:00

So at last if the person is last seen will be more then 10 sec he will go to isconnected =false.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax would change slightly per database.  Here's an example for SQL Server using `not exists`:

```
update  Person
set     IsConnected = 0
where   IsConnected <> 0
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    IsAlive
        where   Person.email = IsAlive.email
                and IsAlive.timestamp > dateadd(s,-10,getdate())
        )
```

Comment: first of all thanks. but im using hsql and what i check it's not support dateadd :-(.

Comment: @dan: Try `TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_SECOND, -10, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` ?